# How to add two 2d arrays of different sizes?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a method that adds two 2d arrays into one 2d array. The new 2d array should add the values from the same positions of each 2d array (`array1[0][0]+array2[0][0]`). The method should also be able to add two 2d arrays of different sizes. Basically, if the 2d arrays have different sizes, the missing values should be treated as 0. I am having trouble with some test cases for adding two 2d arrays into one.
My code works if:

```java
int a[][] = {{211, 21, 32, 34}, {20, 21}};
int b[][] = {{32, 42}, {45, 21}};
```

But it doesn't work when:

```java
int a[][] = {{}, {2}};
int b[][] = {{}, {}};
```

Here is my code so far:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Main {
    public static int[][] go(int[][] matOne, int[][] matTwo) {
        int difr = 0;
        int difc = 0;
        if (matOne.length > matTwo.length) {
            difr = Math.abs(matOne.length - matTwo.length);
        }
        if (matTwo.length > matOne.length) {
            difr = Math.abs(matTwo.length - matOne.length);
        }

        if (matOne[0].length > matTwo[0].length) {
            difc = Math.abs(matOne[0].length - matTwo[0].length);
        }
        if (matTwo[0].length > matOne[0].length) {
            difc = Math.abs(matTwo[0].length - matOne[0].length);
        }

        int c1 = 0;
        int c2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matOne.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matOne[i].length; j++) {
                c1++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matTwo.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matTwo[i].length; j++) {
                c2++;
            }
        }

        int[][] sum = new int[matOne.length][];
        if (c1 > c2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; ++i) {
                sum[i] = new int[matOne[i].length];
                for (int j = 0; j < matOne[i].length; ++j) {
                    sum[i][j] = matOne[i][j];
                }
            }
        } else if (c2 > c1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; ++i) {
                sum[i] = new int[matTwo[i].length];
                for (int j = 0; j < matTwo[i].length; ++j) {
                    sum[i][j] = matTwo[i][j];
                }
            }
        } else {
            int[][] copy = new int[matOne.length][matOne[0].length];
            for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; ++i) {
                sum[i] = new int[copy[i].length];
                for (int j = 0; j < copy[i].length; ++j) {
                    sum[i][j] = copy[i][j];
                }
            }
        }

        int[][] newMatOne = new int[matOne.length+difr][matOne[0].length+difc];
        int[][] newMatTwo = new int[matTwo.length+difr][matTwo[0].length+difc];
        for (int i = 0; i < matOne.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matOne[i].length; j++) {
                newMatOne[i][j] = matOne[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < matTwo.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matTwo[i].length; j++) {
                newMatTwo[i][j] = matTwo[i][j];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sum[i].length; j++) {
                sum[i][j] = newMatOne[i][j] + newMatTwo[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][] = {{2}, {}};
        int b[][] = {{}, {}};
        int[][] z = go(a, b);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(z));
    }
}
```

Comment: "But it doesn't work when:" isnt a valid problem statement. Please always include the actual outcome, see [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I think you're over-complicating things a little. No need to pad the arrays to make them the same size, just clone the longer array and add in values from the smaller array.

I would break this out into two methods, one that handles the addition of two 1D arrays, possibly of different length, and then another that uses this method to handle the 2D case.

```
public static int[] add1D(int[] matOne, int[] matTwo)
{
    if(matTwo.length < matOne.length) 
        return add1D(matTwo, matOne);
    
    int[] arr = matTwo.clone();
    
    for(int i=0; i<matOne.length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] += matOne[i];
    }
    
    return arr;
}
```

Note how we use an initial check on the relative lengths of the two arrays. If the 2nd array is shorter than the first we reverse the arguments. This way we can assume that `matOne` is always shorter or equal in length to `matTwo`, which simplified the code quite a bit.

Now we can handle the 2D case, using the same check on the arguments:

```
public static int[][] add2D(int[][] matOne, int[][] matTwo)
{
    if(matTwo.length < matOne.length) 
        return add2D(matTwo, matOne);
    
    int[][] mat = new int[matTwo.length][];
    
    for(int i=0; i<matOne.length; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = add1D(matOne[i], matTwo[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i=matOne.length; i<matTwo.length; i++)
    {
        mat[i] = matTwo[i].clone();
    }
    
    return mat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I compiled your code and it seemed to work, so I'm not sure what issue you're having on your end, but looking through your code I found the following...

For your first part, because you're using absolute value, you don't need to test which one is bigger, only that they're not equal. i.e.

```java
if (matOne.length != matTwo.length) {
    difr = Math.abs(matOne.length - matTwo.length);
}
```

That handles either case.

Next...
The issue is with the lengths of the empty array, the compiler is reading it as length of 0, which is what is throwing the index out of bounds exception. Basically, to fix this, I've wrapped the part that blows up in a try-catch, you can try to handle this in another way, but this holds the part that doesn't blow up to save into your new array.

```java
public static int[][] go(int[][] matOne, int[][] matTwo) {
    int[][] temp; // to return
    int d1 = (matOne.length > matTwo.length) ? matOne.length : matTwo.length;
    int d2 = (matOne[0].length > matTwo[0].length) ? matOne[0].length : matTwo[0].length;
    temp = new int[d1][d2];
    for (int i = 0; i < d1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < d2; j++) {
            int holdA = 0, holdB = 0;
            try {
                holdA = matOne[i][j];
            } catch (Exception e) { }
            try {
                holdB = matTwo[i][j];
            } catch (Exception e) { }
            temp[i][j] = holdA + holdB;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```